# I want to generate OTP internally using KeyCloak, without external apps like Google Authenticator / FreeOTP

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have a keycloak server and I wish to generate OTP in addition to the access token. My issue is, I am not able to know if Keycloak (version 5.0.0) generates OTP internally or is it necessary to use external apps Google Authenticator/ Free OTP.

Until this moment, I have tried the Google Authenticator OTP option but I am not able to see any option that allows keycloak to generate OTP Codes and validating them without Google Auth or Free OTP.